# CSS: how does medium calculate it's image sizes

Tags: css

I try to understand how medium calculates the the image sizes in their latest list. What I understand is that the image is positioned **absolute** and sizes are coming from the **.aspectRatioPlaceholder-fill** div, which has a 30% padding-bottom.

What I don’t understand, where does the height for calculating the 30% come from ? Can anyone help here out? Thx!

Here is the link: https://medium.com/cinemania

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vertical padding set in percent is calculated on the elements width.
That is really useful in using aspect ratios for elements.
https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Comment: thx, that helped...  I looked higher in the tree and found indeed a maxWidth:'600px'